# Need to generate a structured document out of MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We have a [MongoDB collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections) like this:

```
{
        a : string, nullable
        b : string, nullable
        c : boolean, not nullable
        d : string, nullable
        e : number, nullable 
}
```

out of which we need the result like this:

```
{
       ab : {
              a: <count of a where a is not blank or null>,
              b: <count of b where b is not blank or null>
            },
        c : {
              true: <count of c where c true>,
              false: <count of c where c false>
            },
        d : [<all distinct/unique values of d],
        e : {
              average : <average value of e>,
              min     : <minimum value of e>,
              max     : <maximum value of e>
            }
}
```

> We do not wish to fire multiple [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) queries and manipulate the result in-memory to bring up the results.

How do we achieve this using MongoDB's queries only? Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run multiple pipelines and then combine results. That's possible with [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) operator. Try below query:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            q1: [
                { $match: { a: { $exists: true, $ne: null }  } },
                { $count: "total" }
            ],
            q2: [
                { $match: { b: { $exists: true, $ne: null }  } },
                { $count: "total" }
            ],
            q3: [
                { $match: { c: true } },
                { $count: "total" }
            ],
            q4: [
                { $match: { c: false } },
                { $count: "total" }
            ],
            q5: [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        unique: { $addToSet: "$d" }
                    }
                }
            ],
            q6: [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        average: { $avg: "$e" },
                        min: { $min: "$e" },
                        max: { $max: "$e" },
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            q1: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$q1", 0 ] },
            q2: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$q2", 0 ] },
            q3: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$q3", 0 ] },
            q4: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$q4", 0 ] },
            q5: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$q5", 0 ] },
            q6: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$q6", 0 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "ab.a": { $ifNull: [ "$q1.total", 0 ] },
            "ab.b": { $ifNull: [ "$q2.total", 0 ] },
            "c.true": { $ifNull: [ "$q3.total", 0 ] },
            "c.false": { $ifNull: [ "$q4.total", 0 ] },
            d: "$q5.unique",
            "e.average": "$q6.average",
            "e.min": "$q6.min",
            "e.max": "$q6.max",
        }
    }
])
```

So `q1-q6` are just separate aggregation pipelines. Each of them returns an array of results which can be converted to separate subdocuments using [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html). Then you can use simple `$project` to reshape that into final result. Using [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html) to get unique values for `d` and [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html) to replace those counts when there's no value with default `0`.